# THREE is undefined

Tags: three.js

if i type in the following code and want to see it in the built in browser of  my editor it says THREE is undefined. What s wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Our Javascript will go here.var scene = new THREE.Scene();
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth /      window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: is there a folder named js?and a file three.js inside it? you should make a folder "js" and put "three.js" file

Comment: thanks I thought that THREE  is like a library and the editor would link to it itself. How can it be undefined. it will certainly work if I write a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js<

Comment: @simson it seems that you are very new to javascript.you need to learn about adding external scripts.basically three.js is a javascript file ( library ).you need to include it in your html file.`if I write a href="threejs.org"; target="_blank">three.js<` this is completely misunderstanding.it's just a link to three.js website.read this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_placement.htm
and you can find lot of working three.js examples online.adding three.js is same as adding libraries like jquery.

Comment: ok I ´ll do that. Thanks for your help ;-)